# What is the derivative of the following function?

Tags: derivatives

What is the derivative of

$$\cos(x)^{\sin(x)}$$

I came up with the following, but I don't know if the answer is right:

$$-\sin(x)\cos(x)\ln(\cos(x)\cos(x)^{\sin(x)}$$

Answer (score 2):

With this exponential equations
$$
y = f(x)^{g(x)} \implies \ln y = g(x)\ln f(x)
$$
so taking the derivative of both sides
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln y = \frac{1}{y}y'\\
\frac{d}{dx}g(x)\ln f(x) = g'(x)\ln f(x) + g(x)\frac{1}{f(x)}f'(x)
$$
sub in the functions for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and re-arrange
$$
y' = \left[g'(x)\ln f(x) + g(x)\frac{1}{f(x)}f'(x)\right]y
$$